# MS Access form does not refresh when using ODBC link to MySql

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I have a front-end Access 2007 database connecting to MySql tables using MySQL ODBC connector.

The problem is that a form linked to a table will not refresh its data if the data are changed by another user on the network or if the data was changed by a pop-up form.

If I create a VBA code which detects the change and then refresh the form or requery, then the form which shows many records in a table like format, will jump to its top, and some users will lose the sight of the record which is relevant to them and will have to scroll down to find it again which is not always easy.

Previously, when I was using only Access tables on the network, records would be updated on all access forms if data would change, and the forms would not scroll back to the top...

Is ti possible to make Access form autamaticaly refresh its row if data changed on MySql?

One possible solution is if I could get the form to scroll to the exacly same position after the refresh, but not sure if this can be done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ODBC refresh interval in your Access application.  The default value appears to be 1500 seconds.  Perhaps a lower value will allow your form to display its updated contents without code intervention.

Office button -> Access Options -> Advanced, then find ODBC refresh interval near the end of that section of options.

**Newer Versions of Office**
File -> Options -> Client Settings -> Scroll down to Advanced -> Change ODBC refresh Interval (Sec)

Also, since you have created code to detect data changes on the server, then refresh the forms in response, you could set a bookmark for the form, refresh, and then return to the bookmarked form row.

[Recordset.Bookmark Property (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff823084.aspx)

**Update**: Changing the form's Recordset Type to Dynaset was the key to resolving this one.

Comment: I've just tried ODBC refresh, but interestingly only refreshes the row data if that row is scrolled out of the visible screen and back, otherwise it will not do it on its own even tough I set refresh to 3seconds. As for the bookmark that works but it moves the form to the record and places that record on top of the screen, rather than the position which users remembers. An exact scrolled positon would do much better. Thanks for ODBC settings...

Comment: @Lumis The moment the User selects a record from a list, the list query is no longer the current query

Comment: You seem to be right, Dynaset updates the form without need to requery or do anything else!

Answer (score 1):

Your first question "Is ti possible to make Access form autamaticaly refresh its row if data changed on MySql?" is clearly answerable: **No.**

When Access has populated your form, the representation of data in your form becomes totally independent of the record with the same primary key in the database - MySQL has no knowledge, that you are interested in any changes, so it will not inform Access (in fact: there isn't a mechanism to do so)

Concerning the scroll question: In Access 2000 this was possible by activating the record, which would scroll it into view. I suspect it may be similar with Access 2007

Comment: The problem here is how to make Access refresh its row or entire form without scrolling the form back to the top when longer than the visible screen?

Comment: IIRC The trick was do a `requery` on the form, then active same record that was activated before. Glue this to any "interesting" event