# Mysql tables autofill fields

Tags: mysql, autofill

I have a an access front end coupled to a mysql backend database.  Could anyone tell me if its possible to produce a mysql table which autofills columns (ie) once an entry has been added in column A, column B will autofill with a default text value?

Comment: By definition, a record must have a value in every column.  If you don't provide one explicitly, the `DEFAULT` (which may be `NULL`) will be used.  You can specify alternative `DEFAULT` values in your schema.  If you need non-constant `DEFAULT` values, you can define a trigger to calculate and set it when no explicit value is given.

Comment: See this S.O. question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973029/ms-access-form-does-not-refresh-when-using-odbc-link-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does support default values for columns.  It won't however be able to do this conditionally (i.e. some value based on value in other column) without using a trigger.  To just change the default value on teh column you can run a query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name
SET DEFAULT 'default value'
```